# Dynamic Filter to the SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamicquery

I have a Query like below

```
WITH TempResult AS(
SELECT AccessionNumber FROM [CASE]
UNION ALL
SELECT AccessionNumber FROM CaseReassign), 
TempCount AS (SELECT COUNT(AccessionNumber) AS MaxRows FROM TempResult)
SELECT * FROM TempResult, TempCount
```

Which works fine fetching the rows and its count. But, when 
Can someone help me in how to add a filter dynamically to this select query? say for example I need something like below but it throws an error "Common Table Expression defined but not used"

```
DECLARE @filter nvarchar(max);
SET @filter = 'WHERE AccessionNumber LIKE ''%Case%'''

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

WITH TempResult AS(
SELECT AccessionNumber FROM [CASE]
UNION ALL
SELECT AccessionNumber FROM CaseReassign), 
TempCount AS (SELECT COUNT(AccessionNumber) AS MaxRows FROM TempResult)

SELECT  @sql = 'SELECT * FROM TempResult, TempCount ' + @filter

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: You could put the whole query with the CTE's in the `@sql` variable, concat the SELECT & filter to it, then execute.  A CTE isn't like a #temp table or a table variable.  It's only part of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL defines it's own scope.
Within dynamic SQL you are not able to access local variables. As far as I know this also counts for local defined CTE's.

So you are required to put your CTE into the dynamic SQL I think.